# change circle background color within grid tpl on itemclick

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs5

My grid has in each row a circle.

On row itemclick I need to change the grid circle background color.

I tried the following, but only selects the circle of the first row.

```
     tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',

                 '<span class="circle"></span>',

                //'<input class="radio" id="radioZ" name="radio" type="radio" unchecked>',
                '<div style="float: left; width: 90%; padding:0px;">',
                    '<div style=" padding: 10px 7px 2px 7px;"><b>{name}</b></div>',
                    '<div style=" padding: 10px 7px 2px 7px;">{email}</div>',
                '</div>',
         '</tpl>'
        ]
    }],

   listeners:{
       itemclick: function( grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
           var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.circle');
           var el = Ext.get(dom[0]); 
            el.applyStyles({'background-color':"red"});

       }
   }
```

Fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1btk

Another option is to use a hidden radio button and select it on ItemClick, which in turn triggers an event that changes the circle background color, but this option seems more complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the child element from the row:

`Ext.fly(item).down('.circle').setStyle('background-color', 'red');`